# Choosing routing.yml based on user culture?

Tags: routes, symfony1, culture

In my [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) application I would like to choose the routing.yml based on the current user's culture;

```
'en' => routing.en.yml
'no' => routing.no.yml
```

and so forth.

Any suggestion to how this can be done?

Edit: I am **not** trying to do i18n this way - I use [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony)'s built-in methods for that. I simply want "static" urls to reflect the user's language:

```
/en/projects/internal/project-name
/no/prosjekter/interne/prosjektnavn
/fr/baguette/champs-elysee/foux-de-fafa
```

Where "projects" is a module, the category "internal" and "project-name" are stored in the database.

Comment: @DR: Probably that he wants to have english URLs for the english language site, and norwegian URLs for the norwegian counterpart, e.g. "/very-good" and "/kjempe-fint" ;-)

Comment: @phidah: Fullstendig korrekt - absolutely correct! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a recent website I did. I, however, did not find a proper solution and ended up making all URLs english.

I think you should have a look at the [ysfDimensionsPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ysfDimensionsPlugin) - I haven't checked it out but it might be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The plugin seems interesting. I will look into it.

Comment: Please tell us the results of looking into it ;) We all want to know for the question is really interesting.

Comment: Hi all, it turns out that ysfDimensionsPlugin requires APC and (apparently) only supports Symfony 1.1. Thus, I haven't been able to check it out. Will keep on digging.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to achieve the same thing. In Symfony 1.4 here is what I've did:

Created a domain => culture map in `app.yml`

```
all:
  languages:
    domain_map:
      www.example.com: en
      www.example.it: it
      www.example.es: es
```

Created a `myPatternRouting` class extending the `sfPatternRouting`

```
class myPatternRouting extends sfPatternRouting
{
    public function getConfigFileName()
    {
        $domain_map = sfConfig::get('app_languages_domain_map');
        $domain     = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $culture    = isset($domain_map[$domain]) ? $domain_map[$domain] : 'en';
        $routing    = sprintf('config/routing.%s.yml', $culture);

        return sfContext::getInstance()->getConfigCache()->checkConfig($routing, true);
    }
}
```

Changed the factory for routing in `factories.yml`

```
all:
  routing:
    class: myPatternRouting
```

Created a config handler entry for the new pattern of the routing.yml files into `config_handlers.yml`

```
config/routing.*.yml:
  class:    sfRoutingConfigHandler
```

And then created the routing files as `routing.[culture].yml`

And it works :)

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a way to do this without dynamically loading the routing using a filter. You could override sfPatternRouting and write a custom loadConfiguration function, but you'd need to know the user's culture when the routing class gets instantiated*. If you go the filter route, simply load the proper routing file on the first half of the filter chain.

*If you go this route, make sure you change factories.yml as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is a correct way to implement i18n. What goal are you trying to achieve with this solution? Symfony has all i18n tools built-in and you should have no problems to use integrated ways.

Look here: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/13-I18n-and-L10n and scroll down to the "Culture in the URL" box. It should solve your problem.

Comment: @FractalizeR: Thanks for your reply. However, I am not trying to implement i18n this way; for tha, I use Symfony's built in i18n - both in terms of database content and "hardcoded" values (e.g. labels stored in xliff etc.).

I want to be able to have static urls, based on my modules. The module "projects" in english would be "prosjekter" in norwegian.

An example:
/en/projects/internal/project-name
becomes
/no/prosjekter/interne/prosjektnavn
and
/fr/baguette/champs-elysee/foux-de-fafa

Answer (score 0):

i use  [this plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfLanguageSwitchPlugin). My routes look like this:

```
news_ro:
  url:   /ro/stiri/:slug
  requirements: { sf_culture: (?:ro),  page: \d+  }
  param: { module: news, action: index, page: 1, sf_culture: ro}


news_en:
  url:   /en/news/:slug
  requirements: { sf_culture: (?:en),  page: \d+  }
  param: { module: news, action: index, page: 1, sf_culture: en }
```

I take the slug basen on the current culture.